# How to display images from tf.image.crop_and_resize

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have to apply `tf.image.crop_and_resize` on my images and want to generate 5 boxes from each image. I have written the below code which works fine

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Load the pre-trained Xception model to be used as the base encoder.
xception = keras.applications.Xception(
    include_top=False, weights="imagenet", pooling="avg"
)
# Set the trainability of the base encoder.
for layer in xception.layers:
  layer.trainable = False
# Receive the images as inputs.
inputs = layers.Input(shape=(299, 299, 3), name="image_input")

input ='/content/1.png'

input = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(input,target_size=(299,299,3))
image = tf.expand_dims(np.asarray(input)/255, axis=0)
BATCH_SIZE = 1
NUM_BOXES = 5
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 256
IMAGE_WIDTH = 256
CHANNELS = 3
CROP_SIZE = (24, 24)


boxes = tf.random.uniform(shape=(NUM_BOXES, 4))
box_indices = tf.random.uniform(shape=(NUM_BOXES,), minval=0, maxval=BATCH_SIZE, dtype=tf.int32)


output = tf.image.crop_and_resize(image, boxes, box_indices, CROP_SIZE)
xception_input = tf.keras.applications.xception.preprocess_input(output)
```

The above code works fine however when I want to display these boxes I run below code

```
for i in range(5):

  # define subplot
  plt.subplot(330 + 1 + i)

  # generate batch of images
  batch = xception_input.next()

  # convert to unsigned integers for viewing
  image = batch[0].astype('uint8')

  image = np.reshape(24,24,3)

  # plot raw pixel data
  plt.imshow(image)

#show the figure
plt.show()
```

But it generates this error `AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'next'`.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: full error should show which line makes problem.

Comment: why do you use `.next()`? Maybe you should use `xception_input[i]`. OR maybe it is totaly wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `[i]` instead of `.next()`

And there is also problem with converting it to `uint8` (but it doesn't need to `reshape`)

```
for i in range(5):

  plt.subplot(331 + i)

  tensor = xception_input[i]
  #print(tensor)

  tensor = tensor*255
  image = np.array(tensor, dtype=np.uint8)
  #print(image)

  plt.imshow(image)
```

or use `for` to get items

```
for i, tensor in enumerate(xception_input):
  #print(tensor)

  plt.subplot(331 + i)

  tensor = tensor*255
  image = np.array(tensor, dtype=np.uint8)
  #print(image)

  plt.imshow(image)
```

I don't know what your code should do but this gives me empty images because `tensor` has values like `-0.9` and it convert it all to `0`

Comment: Thanks @furas, Your answer is really helpful. I think I am normalzing my image in upper part of the code in such a way which completely demolishes all the values.

Comment: But I found the problem if we print `tensor = output[i]` then it prints the images.

Comment: But I don't understand why `xception_input` prints all black?

Comment: as I said it gives tensor with similar values like `-0.9` and ti covnerts it al to `0` which gives black color. Documentation for [xception](https://keras.io/api/applications/xception/) I found `xception.preprocess_input will scale input pixels between -1 and 1.` - and maybe you have to rescale it back to `0...255`. There is also link to [examples](https://keras.io/api/applications/#usage-examples-for-image-classification-models) and they use `xception` to create data for `predict()`, not to display it. Maybe you should display `output` instead of `preprocess_input(output)`

Comment: Thanks @furas, your comment is helpful.